# What is socially acceptable for treatment of holidays by an employer?

Tags: company-culture, holidays

I am U.S. based, so biases may show through. It seems common for companies to host a pot luck lunch or post a well-wishing message or something along those lines. However, if a company doesn't acknowledge the existence of a national holiday at all, is it appropriate to approach HR, and ask about this?

Comment: The title of your question is rather confusing and your post itself is also unclear. Are you simple wondering whether you can ask HR to organise something for a holiday they don't (currently) do anything for?

Comment: You can always ask... But there are many holidays which only some companies observe, and many don't do in-office celebrations at all, so I'm not sure you have much basis for complaining.

Comment: For a common holiday, is it considered OK to completely ignore it, if you're an employer?

Comment: Yes, it is considered OK to completely ignore it. Particularly if you have a diverse workforce, some probably don't celebrate the holiday at all. Also, if a group wants to put together a pot luck (self-funded) that usually acceptable. The company is not often providing any funds for the potluck.

Comment: By *ignoring* a holiday, do you mean they refuse to acknowledge that it is a holiday (as in, you are required to show up for work), or that they do not organize anything to "celebrate" the event?

Comment: The former. I was thinking of celebration as one manifestation of acknowledgement.

Comment: Is "a holiday" a politically correct version of "christmas" or are you really asking why they don't celebrate Easter? I'm not sure but some holidays just don't align with celebration. "Hey, our savior died under torture, happy holidays all, first round is on the company!"

Comment: I must work for weird employers. Except for some day in advance of the Fourth of July or Thanksgiving, the only "holidays" where my employers have called for a potluck are not national holidays. Examples: Pi Day (March 14): The employer supplies the meat, maybe the veggies; the employees supply the pies. Anniversary Day (the day the company was founded) or Celebration Day (e.g., we just won contract X): The employer supplies the meat, maybe the booze; the employees supply the other stuff.

Comment: How is this closed, after I marked it as Answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if a company doesn't acknowledge the existence of a national
>   holiday at all, is it appropriate to approach HR, and ask about this?

You should be able to ask HR anything, assuming you do so respectfully, without accusations, and you actually want to hear the answer. So yes, it's perfectly appropriate.

Something like "I noticed that our company doesn't do anything for [insert national holiday here]. I was wondering why." shouldn't cause any problems.

You may very well get an answer along the lines of "Well, we have [number] days on our holiday calendar already and we think that's enough. And we celebrate [holiday 1, holiday 2, holiday 3, etc] as well." You may also hear something like "Well we haven't found anyone willing to organize a celebration of [insert national holiday here]. Do you want to volunteer?" So be ready for that.

And some companies just don't get in the habit of "celebrating" holidays within the office at all. This is often because there are many, many occasions that at least one person would like to see celebrated (I'm partial to March 27th - "[National Joe Day](http://www.allthingsquality.com/2011/03/its-national-joe-day.html)").

Either way, HR should be able to explain it to you.